# Why does ConcurrentLruCache in Spring still use thread-safe maps and queues instead of ordinary maps and queues even when read-write lock are used?

Tags: java, spring, lru

[spring-framework/ConcurrentLruCache.java at main · spring-projects/spring-framework · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ConcurrentLruCache.java)

##### Update

Because there may be multiple readers writing to the queue concurrently, the queue must use a thread-safe data structure, and the put operation of the cache is done in the write lock, can the implementation of the cache be replaced with a HashMap? Because the get method of ConcurrentHashMap is implemented without lock.

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)

From [ConcurrentHashMap (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the get method. The choices made   to maximize the number of concurrent readers mean the code doesn't enforce the exclusion needed to be able to use non-threadsafe collections.

The cache is accessed without any lock held. The authors want to avoid having to acquire a lock just to read from the cache.

The queue is accessed with a read lock, so there can be multiple concurrent readers. That requires the queue implementation to be threadsafe.

(Of course if the code used a read lock to read from the cache, then the same issue with multiple readers would be true for the cache as well.)

For the question about using hashmap instead of CHM, part of what you get from using locks is memory visibility. If you use HashMap then when the cache is updated the get method also needs to lock in order to avoid all the issues around insufficiently-synchronized code like JIT optimizations and reorderings.

Comment: Now I understand that the queue must be implemented thread-safely, because there may be multiple readers writing to the queue concurrently. But what about cache? Is it possible to use HashMap instead, because only get calls are executed outside the lock.

Comment: @Poison: no, the cache has to be updated, so both the puts and gets would need locking.

Comment: In the get method of ConcurrentHashMap, it is implemented without lock. If we use HashMap with write lock, can it replace ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: @Poison: yes but it seems like it would be slower. The linked code reads from the cache to try to avoid taking even a read lock.

Comment: Sorry, I may not describe clearly. In the operation of ConcurrentLruCache on the cache, the put method is called in the write lock, and only the get method and the contains method are called outside the lock. Does it mean that we can replace the implementation with HashMap?

Comment: @Poison: no that doesn't work.  I tried to address that in the answer.

Comment: The implementation of the get method of ConcurrentHashMap is not locked. How does it solve the problem of insufficiently-synchronized code?

Comment: Nathan’s answer is right. Let’s put it another way: how would you implement the Least Recently Used (LRU) part of the algorithm with a ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: @BrianClozel In the current implementation of ConcurrentLruCache, because there is a write lock, only one thread will call the put method on the cache at a time. Why use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap?

Comment: to prevent inconsistencies between the read queue, the size of the cache and the content of the hash map.

Comment: @BrianClozel Is the write lock already able to ensure the thread safety of the cache, and is it okay to use HashMap as the cache?

Comment: I don't see how I could convince you in the comments section here. You can try it for yourself and submit a PR if you think this is a viable change.